# Ubuntu 12.04 server will not resolve

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am at a loss as to why I can't resolve. I am sure I am missing something and I hope someone can help.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 server. After setting to static, I can not resolve host names (to be fair I did not test it while it was DHCP).

My LAN IP for my router is 10.0.1.1 and in most cases this will resolve DNS but I changed to Open DNS servers just in case.

But I still get:

```
root@WCULS-1:~# host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This is my current `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.1.0
broadcast 10.0.1.255
gatway 10.0.1.1
```

`/etc/resolvconfig/resolv.confd/base`

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Could add to the question the results of these commands. Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t then run these 4 commands: `ping -c 3 10.0.1.1` , `ping -c 3 208.67.222.222` , `route` , `more /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Check the gateway its misspelled

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard file location `/etc/resolvconfig/resolv.confd/base` - did you mean `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I misspelled gateway in /etc/network/interfaces once I made the spelling correction this solved my lookup problem.